# Can I Reduce Library's Log Level In .NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core

I am using `S2SAuthenticationHandler` from `Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S` namespace for authentication in a .NET Core service.

When authentication failed, there are many redundant error logs that **I would prefer as warnings** (for example, if the token is expired - I prefer not to see any errors).

If I set the **minimum** log level as **Critical** (to avoid **Error** logs), I miss some information about the authentication failure reasons.

Is there any way to **reduce the library's error log level to warning**?

Thanks!

```
services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddS2SAuthentication(services, authManager, options =>
            {
                var events = new S2SAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnTokenValidated = validatedToken =>
                    {
                        validatedToken.Principal = FixClaims(validatedToken.AuthenticationTicket);
                        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationMessageReceived = context =>
                    {
                        context.S2SContext = new S2SContext(Guid.NewGuid()) { CaptureLogs = true };
                        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                    },
                    OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        // This exception do not the authentication failure reason
                        logger.LogWarning(context.Exception, "Authentication failed, exception might contain additional details");
                        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
                    }
                };

                options.Events = events;
            })
```

Comment: @SnowGroomer OP is talking about some log messages from the library declared as ERRORs and he would categorize them as WARNING

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what logging framework you are using currently, but you can generally specify the log level depending on the conditions you set in your code accordingly.

NLog for example allows you to name your logger, and you can set the verbosity for that logger accordingly. You can name your loggers for example based on the root namespace of your assembly.

See: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#targets

Comment: If I understood correctly, the article you are referring to is talking about changing the **minimum log level** as well.
I would like to change the library's error logs - to be warning logs.
I am using the .NET Core's ILogger<> but I guess it doesn't matter since the library is handling their logging in a different manner then my service right?

Comment: Is this of any help to you? Read the section ´Configure Logging´ in particular. You should be able to filter on either categories or providers. [.NET Core Logging Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-logging)

Comment: Unfortunately no, since this configuration are for setting minimum log level:
"The LogLevel specifies the minimum level to log for selected categories".

What I want is to make library's error logs appear as warning logs in my service

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Omer, without catching and re-sending the log event at a different log level, this is not possible.